# Changing activities: Reloading Activities, slowing down - why is this?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Activity `GameActivity`: The page that's opened when the application is first opened.
Activity `GameMain`: The playing activity of the game.
Activity `GameWin`: Transfers to the next `GameActivity` (eventually will have a "You win!" screen, with stats and things)

1. Application is started
2. This is triggered:

   ```
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameMain.class);
           intent.putExtra("level",1);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
       }

   });
   ```
3. `GameMain` has now loaded. The character, `circle`, is now on the left side of the screen.
4. When `circle` gets to the right side of the screen, this if statement inside my game loop now becomes true:

   ```
       if ((circle.x+width/2 > end.startx) && (circle.x-width/2 < end.stopx) && (circle.y+circle.size==end.starty-width/2)) {
               layout.removeAllViews();    
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameWin.class);
               intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               intent.putExtra("level",level);
               finish();
               startActivity(intent);
       }
   ```
5. `GameWin` screen does this:

   ```
       Log.v(TAG,"Goint to level: "+(level+1));
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameMain.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       intent.putExtra("level",(level+1));
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
   ```
6. Sometimes it works, and goes to `GameMain` with level data as 2, just considerably slower than if I went through the level screen and straight to level2. Sometimes it works, and goes to `GameMain` with level data as 2, and reloads the page over and over and over again. Sometimes, my phone restarts.
7. If I have the ability to complete level 2, I do so. Level 3 is even slower if it works, or refreshes, or restarts the phone.
8. If I click "Home" at any time, it goes to my home screen but the application **opens itself** back to the `GameMain` with the last level (back to step 6 or 7).

What am I doing wrong?

API Level 8, LG P500 (2.3.3)

**It turns out this wasn't the problem. The game loop was still running in the background.**

Comment: If anyone needs any more information request it here and I will edit the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was only partially the issue of the intent; the main issue was that I **wasn't stopping the gameloop**.

When the gameloop stopped, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things to try:

1. In GameMain, make sure you call `startActivity(intent)` before `finish()`
2. Add [noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) to the activities in your manifest and set to true

*Edit* You should start adding logging statements to your functions and callbacks.  This will show you what is running and give you timing information on how long it's taking.  Example:

```
onCreate(){
   Log.i(TAG, "onCreate++");
   super.onCreate();

   //other code here

   Log.i(TAG, "onCreate--");
}
```

Comment: Start adding in logging statements, you can never go wrong by starting with a high-level view of what's getting called in your app.

Comment: I used Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY which is working so far, but it seems from my logging that the activities are simply not closing, even with finish(). Why is that?

Comment: Solved it, Error 454. Game loop was still running.